# Incorrect binding redirect in TFS 2015 TFSBuildServiceHost.exe.config

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfsbuild, assembly-binding-redirect

After upgrading a XAML build server from TFS 2013 Update 4 to TFS 2015 Update 1, some XAML builds based on older templates started to fail with the following error:

> TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build
>   definition :  Exception Message: **Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation, Version=14.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. (type FileNotFoundException) 
>   Exception Stack Trace:
>
> ....
>
> Inner Exception Details:
>
> Exception Message: **Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation, Version=11.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. (type  FileNotFoundException)

This is despite `Microsoft.TeamFoundation`, Version=11.0.0.0 existing in the GAC and the builds having functioned fine with TFS 2013. Taking a look at TFSBuildServiceHost.exe.config the following binding redirect has been introduced in TFS 2015:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.TeamFoundation" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-12.9.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

The problem here is that `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll` does not exist post version 11.0.0.0. My understanding is that all namespaces in `Microsoft.TeamFoundation` were merged into `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common` in TFS 2013. The binding redirect is redirecting to a version of an assembly that does not exist.

Removing the redirect allows the builds to succeed.

Is this as a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a bug. Since you have upgraded a XAML build server from TFS 2013 Update 4 to TFS 2015 Update 1. So, it will redirect all the old dll version to the new 14.0.0.0 just like you see.

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.TeamFoundation" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-12.9.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

And to upgrade your build definitions. You have to **recompile any custom activity assemblies** that this build machine uses to target new net framework. Since there is no `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll=14.0.0.0`  You need to delete the reference of this dll in old build definition and refer to a new one which have 14.0.0.0 version.  More details you can check this MSDN blog: [Upgrading your build definitions from TFS2010 to TFS2012](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpricket/2012/10/24/upgrading-your-build-definitions-from-tfs2010-to-tfs2012/)

Comment: Hi Patrick. Thanks for the reply but I am afraid I disagree. `Microsoft.TeamFoundation` version 14.0.0.0 is a **non-existent assembly**. `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll` stopped being shipped after TFS 2012. How can that be valid configuration?